# Neumorphic Design

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

Trying to make the button as shown  in android

[image: Neumorphic buttons]

tried libraries like   https://github.com/fornewid/neumorphism

which make it as

[image]

```
<soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView

    android:id="@+id/card_tranfer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_90sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_85sdp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:neumorph_shadowColorLight="#F4F7F4"
    app:neumorph_shapeType="flat"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_11sdp"
    app:neumorph_backgroundColor="#EFF0EF"
    app:neumorph_cornerFamily="rounded"
    app:neumorph_cornerSize ="18dp"
    app:neumorph_inset="5dp"
    >
```

unable to achieve the shadow of the button as per the first image

Comment: You just need to use simple MaterialCardView and give more margin to them and give higher amount of cardElevation.